# Using functions that return placeholder types defined in another translation unit

Tags: c++, auto, c++14, return-type-deduction, translation-unit

I'm having some trouble understanding how the C++14 extension of the `auto` type-specifier described in [N3638](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3638.html) can possibly be implemented, and what, exactly, is allowed.

Specifically, one of the changes to the standard says,

> If the declared return type of the function contains a placeholder type, the return type of the function is deduced from return statements in the body of the function, if any.

It is easy enough to see how this works when body of the function is in the same file as the declaration; but consider the case where a header file declares a method using the `auto` placeholder but *does not define* it. How can translation units that include this header file but do *not* include the file that defines the method be successfully compiled?

For instance, given the file `foo.hpp`:

```
class foo
{
  public:
    auto gen_data();
};
```

...and file `foo.cpp`:

```
struct data_struct
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  double x;
  char data[37];
};

auto foo::gen_data()
{
  data_struct d;
  // initialize members in d...
  return d;
}
```

...and file `main.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.hpp"

template<typename T>
double get_x(T f)
{
  return f.gen_data().x;
}

int make_and_get_x()
{
  foo f;
  return get_x<foo>(f);
}
```

...is it legal to compile `main.cpp` on its own? If not, why not? If so, how is `get_x` instantiated, since there's no way for the compiler to know whether or not the return type of `gen_data` even has a member named `x`, let alone what its offset is?

This seems like it would be a problem even without worrying about template instantiation, though; for instance, what would happen if you tried accessing `f.gen_data().x` directly, or passing it to a function?

Comment: It's not legal because the compiler has to deduce the return type in each translation unit where it's required (for the type of an expression containing the function call). However, I'm not sure how to deduce that from the standard.

Answer (score 2):

The applicable rule is found in §7.1.6.4 [dcl.spec.auto]/p11:

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed
>   to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed.

There's an example:

```
auto f();
void g() { &f; }  // error, f’s return type is unknown
```

You need the type of `gen_data` to determine the type of the expression `x.gen_data()`; hence the program is ill-formed. To use such a function, the definition must be visible to the compiler.

Comment: Is there anything to prove that the deduction needs to be performed "by the compiler" / in the translation unit where the return type is required? That would be great.

Comment: A language lawyer could claim "well the return type has been deduced in another translation unit". So I'm looking for something that says that "undeduced" means "undeduced in the current translation unit". (For template instantiation, I think the ODR implies this.)

Comment: @dyp Hmm, I see what you are mean. I don't think I see anything explicitly saying that...

Comment: Yes, @dyp's "language-lawyer" concern is more or less what I'm trying to get at in my question. There's no such thing as an "undeduced placeholder type" at link time; "undeduced" necessarily means "undeduced at a particular point in the compilation process." Is there something in the standard clarifying exactly when the compiler needs to be able to deduce the real type of an undeduced placeholder?