# Is using explicit return type in one translation unit and deduced return type in another allowed?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, auto

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746467/using-functions-that-return-placeholder-types-defined-in-another-translation-uni), but subtly different.

Suppose I have two translation units, `exec.cpp` and `lib.cpp`, as followed:

```cpp
// exec.cpp

int foo();

int main() {
    return foo();
}
```

and

```cpp
// lib.cpp

auto foo() {
    return 42;
}
```

Is it legal to compile and link them together? Or is it ill-formed NDR?

Note: both g++ and clang generate the expected executable (i.e. returns 42) with command `<compiler> exec.cpp lib.cpp -o program`

Note: **Arguably this is a bad practice** (as the return type can change if the implementation changes, and breaks the code). But I still would like to know the answer.

Comment: Even if it is not illegal it will lead to subtle issues in the long run that may be hard to debug and thus cost you time in the long run. Why take the chance.

Comment: @MartinYork I wouldn't take the chance :) But still curious if this legal or not.

Comment: `auto` doesn't represent any extra type, it is just a convenience not specifying it explicitly. Return type of `foo` in `exec.cpp` is still `int` so everything is just fine. The only danger is that someone will modify a code and by misstate change return type.

Comment: If the declaration `int foo();` is in scope in `lib.cpp`, as it would be if you used headers in the usual way, you get an error.

Comment: Don't answer in the comments, people

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, since the standard says you cannot redeclare an auto return type function with an explicit type. But does delcaring in another translation unit consist "redeclaration"?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Not so. There is only one definition.

Comment: _But does delcaring in another translation unit consist "redeclaration"?_ Not in your case, at least according to [the current wording](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def#1.sentence-3).

Comment: I'd expect http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#11 to be the controlling rule here, but I don't think it's particularly clear how to interpret "the same type" in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4861: March 2020 post-Prague working draft/C++20 DIS.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/).*</sub>

---

From [[basic.link]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.link#11) [**emphasis** mine]:

> **After all adjustments of types** (during which typedefs are replaced by their definitions), **the types specified by all declarations referring to a given** variable or **function shall be identical**, except that declarations for an array object can specify array types that differ by the presence or absence of a major array bound ([dcl.array]). A violation of this rule on type identity does not require a diagnostic.

[[dcl.spec.auto]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.spec.auto#3) covers that a placeholder type can appear with a function declarator, and if this declarator does not include a *trailing-return-type* (as is the case of OP's example)

> [...] Otherwise [no *trailing-return-type*], the function declarator **shall declare a function**.

where

> [...] the return type of the function is deduced from non-discarded `return` statements, if any, in the body of the function ([stmt.if]).

[[dcl.fct]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct#1) covers function declarators that do not include a *trailing-return-type* [**emphasis** mine, removing *opt* parts of the grammar that do not apply in this particular example]:

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form [...] **the type of the *declarator-id* in `D` is** “*derived-declarator-type-list* function of *parameter-type-list* returning `T`” [...]

Thus, the two declarations

```
int f();      // #1
auto foo() {  // #2
    // [dcl.spec.auto]/3:
    // return type deduced to 'int'
}
```

both declare functions where the type of the associated *declarator-id* in `D` of these `T D` declarations is

> “*derived-declarator-type-list* function of *parameter-type-list* returning `T`”

where in both cases, `T` is `int`:

- explicitly specified in `#1`,
- deduced as per [dcl.spec.auto]/3 in `#2`.

Thus, the declarations `#1` and `#2`, after all adjustments of types, have identical (function) types, thus fulfilling [basic.link]/11, and the OP's example is well-formed. Any slight variation of the definition of `auto f()`, however, could lead to a deduced return type which is not `int`, in which case [basic.link]/11 is violated, NDR.